Approximation of smooth real functions with an integer integral by a sum of $\delta$-functions with coefficients $\pm 1$
This question arose from a quantum physics research (my article Entropy 2022, 24(2), 261, where I considered approximation of a smooth charge density (built from a wave function) by a collection of point-like particles and antiparticles with quantized charge).
Let us consider a smooth real function $f(\boldsymbol{x})$ in a $d$-dimensional cube $C$:$-\pi\leq x^i\leq\pi$, where $\boldsymbol{x}=(x^1,\ldots,x^d)$, $1\leq i\leq d$, $\int\limits_C f(\boldsymbol{x})\boldsymbol{dx}=1$, and $f(\boldsymbol{x})$ vanishes on the boundary of the cube.
Let us also consider distributions of the form $$g(\boldsymbol{x})=\sum_{n=1}^{2j+1}(-1)^{n+1}\delta(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{x}_n),$$where $\delta(\boldsymbol{x})$ is the $d$-dimensional Dirac's $\delta$-function, and $\boldsymbol{x}_n$ belong to the interior of $C$.
$f(\boldsymbol{x})$ and $g(\boldsymbol{x})$ in the cube can be expanded in Fourier series with terms of the form $a_\boldsymbol{k}\exp{(i\boldsymbol{k}\boldsymbol{x}})$, where $d$-dimensional vectors $\boldsymbol{k}=(k^1,\ldots,k^d)$ have integer coordinates (or the series can involve sines and cosines). For some natural $m$, the series can be truncated by keeping only terms with such $\boldsymbol{k}$ that $|k^i|\leq m$.
I suspect that the following statement is true:
$\forall m$ $\exists$ $j$ and $\boldsymbol{x}_n$ ($1\leq n\leq 2j+1$) such that the truncated Fourier series for $f(\boldsymbol{x})$ and $g(\boldsymbol{x})$ coincide.
The reason to think so is that, on the one hand, the coincidence of the truncated series is equivalent to existence of roots of some polynomial system, on the other hand, the number of the unknowns of the system can be arbitrarily large. However, it is not obvious that real solutions for $\boldsymbol{x}_n$ can be found for a sufficiently large $j$. I was only able to prove the statement for $d=1$ (my article Quantum Rep. 2022, 4(4), 486-508, Section 2.8). However, I was not able to prove the statement for $d>1$ because of difficulties with vectors $\boldsymbol{k}$ that have some zero coordinates.
I would much appreciate some ideas of the proof (preferably constructive) for $d>1$ (say, $d=3$). Besides, I cannot be sure that similar problems have not been considered by others, so I would also be grateful for references.

I can do the easy part (to show how to prove the statement you need) but I'll have to leave the difficult part (to find out who, when, and where obtained this result for the first time) to someone else. The argument is based on my AoPS post from long ago, so you'll have to read and understand it first before reading the rest of this answer. Once that is done, the rest of the argument is as follows:
We put one delta-measure wherever you want to get the $0$-th coefficient right and the rest will be composed of dipoles $\delta(x-a)-\delta(x-b)$. Let $K$ be the set of all sequences of the Fourier coefficients of interest with respect to the $\sin/\cos$ system (to keep everything within the real domain) of such dipoles when $a,b$ run over $[-\pi,\pi]^d$ (you can go slightly inside, if you want, though how much depends on how many Fourier coefficients you want to handle). Now the diameter of $K$ in the corresponding finite dimensional Euclidean space is some fixed quantity and, most importantly, $K$ is connected. On the other hand, the convex hull of $K$ contains a small ball (if you have any trigonometric polynomial including only non-zero frequencies and of $L^2$ norm $1$, then we can find a dipole with respect to which its integral is at least $1$). Hence the convex hull of the Minkowski sum $K+\dots+K$ contains as large ball as we wish and, thereby, the sum itself contains as large ball as we wish, provided that the number of summands is large enough. The End.
P.S. My initial application of that lemma was completely different and I managed to bypass it before I found its proof, so it was just hanging in the air all these years. It is funny that it turned out to be useful now. Also I wouldn't call this proof "constructive" but I strongly suspect that some high-dimensional analogue of the intermediate value theorem has to be involved (I essentially used Brouwers fixed point theorem), so, perhaps, one cannot do much better. I will be happy to get proved wrong on that account, of course :-)

Fantastic... Thank you very much indeed. It will take me some time to understand your proof. By the way, what was your initial application?

@akhmeteli It will take me some time to understand your proof. Feel free to ask as many questions as you need. Note that the proof is not entirely self-contained: it relies upon the classical permutation lemma saying that if you have a set of vectors of norm $\le 1$ in $\mathbb R^D$ with sum $0$, then you can arrange them in such an order that all partial sums will be bounded by $D$ in norm. The initial application was to construct the Dirichlet series with some fancy properties (I'm not sure I even remember the details now: it was another question someone asked somewhere).

Thank you very much. So I am slowly going through the proof (busy with other things). I guess the boundary from your comment for the "classical permutation lemma" was proven in https://www.mathnet.ru/links/de5273b00c5f18d3129ba8b3a5918530/faa1805.pdf .

@akhmeteli Yep, though I'm not really concerned too much with the exact bound here as long as it depends on the dimension only, so any other bound and proof of it are fine for my purposes too.

Yes, I understand that. "if you have any trigonometric polynomial including only non-zero frequencies and of $L^2$ norm 1, then we can find a dipole with respect to which its integral is at least 1" Without worrying about the specific value of the constant, the scalar product of a vector built from arbitrary coefficients of a truncated real Fourier series $a_n,b_n$ and Fourier coefficients of a dipole will be a difference of Fourier series with arguments $a$ and $b$ instead of $x$. The lower bound for maximum of the square of one such series can be estimated using Parseval theorem. (cntd.)

So one of the arguments ($a$ or $b$) can be chosen to provide the maximum square of the Fourier series, which is positive. The other argument ($a$ or $b$) can be chosen in such a way that the Fourier series vanishes. So I guess I have an idea how to prove the quoted statement. Will be sifting through your proof further.

@akhmeteli Yep, though my idea was rather to choose $a$ at the maximum of the polynomial (truncated Fourier series) and $b$ at the minimum, but what you said works perfectly well too.

Thank you very much. Now I am trying to trace the details of the connection between your AoPS post and the post here, namely, the connection between $K$ here and $K_i$ in AoPS. So $K_i$ "is contained in the ball of radius $ \delta$ centered at the origin", while "the convex hull of $K$ contains a small ball". I am not sure at the moment if $K$ itself contains a small ball, but let us assume it does. We can limit $K$ to this small ball to be able to use the  AoPS statement, but it is not obvious that such a subset of $K$ will be connected. Is this a problem, or (cntd.)

do I miss an easy fix? I appreciate that "the diameter of $K$ in the corresponding finite dimensional Euclidean space is some fixed quantity", but it cannot be arbitrarily small, while we need $\delta$ "to be able to be" small. The following comment may be irrelevant or trivial, but I'd like to note that we cannot use fractions of dipoles (again, I am not sure it is relevant to "convex hull" of your posts).

@akhmeteli It is just trivial scaling. We need $\delta$ to be small compared to $1$ in the AoPS post, while here we need the fixed quantity (the diameter of $K$) to be small compared to the radius of the ball contained in the convex hull of $K+\dots+K$, which can be made arbitrarily large (it is just the number of terms times the radius of the ball contained in the convex hull of $K$). In other words, if the convex hull of $K$ contains a ball of radius $r$, we apply the AoPS lemma to $K'=\frac 2RK$ where $R$ is huge. Continued

@akhmeteli  Then if we take $R/r$ copies of $K'$, the convex hull of the sum contains the ball of radius $2$, so the sum contains the ball of radius $1$, which is equivalent to the sum of $K$ containing the ball of radius $R$. We just need to choose $R>\frac {2\operatorname{diam}K}{\delta}$ to start with.

Thank you very much indeed! Actually, I am glad I asked this trivial question because a related question on your AoPS post arose and your answer seems relevant to this question as well. “Suppose that $K_i$ ($i=1,\ldots,n$) are compact connected sets in $R^d$ such that each set is contained in the ball of radius $\delta$ centered at the origin and the sum $K_1+\ldots+K_n={y_1+\ldots+y_n:y_i\in K_i}$ is not contained in any half-space ${ y: (y,e)\leq 2}$ where $e$ is any unit vector and $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the usual (cntd.)

scalar product. Show that if $\delta>0$ is small enough, then this sum must contain the unit ball centered at the origin." I am afraid I don't quite understand what it means. I would think “if $\delta>0$ is small enough” assumes some process of decreasing $\delta$. But do $K_i$ change as $\delta$ decreases? They probably should, otherwise they eventually will not be contained in the ball of radius $\delta$. But if they change arbitrarily, the statement does not seem correct in a general case. Then how are the new $K_i$ related to the old ones? (cntd.)

Are they intersections of the old $K_i$ with the ball having the radius of the new $\delta$? So I don’t understand this statement, however if we move in the opposite direction, keeping $\delta$ constant and increasing “the radius of the ball contained in the convex hull of $K$", the statement seems to make sense. I am still moving towards better understanding of your proof.

@akhmeteli It means "For every $d$, there exists $\delta=\delta(d)>0$ such that for every set of compact sets $K_i$ ($i=1,\dots n$) such that the diameters of all $K_i$ are less than $\delta$, $K_i$ are connected, and the convex hull of $K_1+\dots+K_n$ contains the ball of radius $2$ centered at the origin, the sum itself contains the ball of radius $1$ centered at the origin." Now all quantifiers have been spelled out. Feel free to ask more questions if something is still unclear :-)

Thank you so much! Now it makes sense. The statement in your AoPS post looked somewhat confusing: $K_i$ and $n$ were mentioned first, and then there was this phrase “Show that if $\delta>0$ is small enough”, so it looked like $\delta$ depends on $K_i$ and $n$, whereas it seems to only depend on $d$. And I was wrong saying “But if they change arbitrarily, the statement does not seem correct in a general case.”

@akhmeteli Yep, it wasn't  a writing  of exemplary  clarity, indeed :lol: Jmerry had the same problem with it as you. But I hope the proof was still understandable without too much effort.

Yes, I had taken note of jmerry's comment, but jmerry only mentioned $n$, and I worried more about $K_i$, although these issues are closely related. Until recently, I was pretty sure that the statement from your previous comment was incorrect, but when I tried to prove that...:-) (cntd.)

As for "understandable"... Your proof is fabulous, and "daryonomu konyu..." https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/look%20a%20gift%20horse%20in%20the%20mouth . However, I may try to write up your proof (of course, without any claim to originality) to customize it for my application and make it more accessible to us, lowly physicists:-)

@akhmeteli "However, I may try to write up your proof" Sure. Everything I put in the public domain is free for everyone to use and to spread without any special permission :-) That is, IMHO, the whole point of communication, scientific or otherwise.
